# I am having an issue creating relations in SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Tags: sql-server, azure

When I try to create relations I get an error

> "Failed to retrieve data for this request - unknown property
>   IsAccessible"

. The designer window shows up but the `tables` not listed at all... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is with the current version of sql-server. You should  update the version of sql-server you are using and try creating relations.